# Where can i find an API that locates stores by zip code and name?

Tags: c#, json, google-maps

I am making an app that requires me to find the latitude or longitude of stores based on the zip code and name of the store the user gives. But i need an API to do this. I read some things on Google that there is a maps API that can help me with this. But i do not know how to locate the API. Google's developers site is quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Google GeoCoding API` mentioned here -

[The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding)

You can get latitude and longitude from address here -

[Geocoding (Latitude/Longitude Lookup)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#geocoding)

And here the instructions before you start to get an API key and other details -

[Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)